# Какой тип запроса выполняется через адресную строку

Tags: html, http

Я решаю тест по основам HTML. Попался следующий вопрос: какой тип запроса выполняется через адресную строку?

Я знаю, что при создании форм в атрибуте `method` тега `form` указывается тип запроса `GET` или `POST`. Я также вижу, что если задать `POST`, то при отправке формы в адресной строке ничего не поменяется, в отличие от `GET` (туда будут включены данные из формы). Ответ предполагает выбор одного из вариантов `POST`, `GET`, `MEDIA`, `STREAM`, но методы `MEDIA` и `STREAM` не описаны в спецификации протокола HTTP. Таким образом напрашивается ответ `GET`.
Я предполагаю, что ход моих мыслей может быть неверным, поэтому прошу написать, как бы ответили вы и *почему*? Интересен обоснованный ответ.

Comment: Именно, это вопрос из теста. В изученной мною литературе (для новичков) ответа нет и найти информацию во вне в первом приближении не получилось. Есть желание сэкономить время, поэтому буду благодарен за помощь. Интересует не галочка напротив верного ответа, а почему (и где почитать). Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Потратил не менее 5 часов на поиск ответа в интернете. Это категорически много для одного, не основного в данный момент вопроса. Поэтому,  @Pyramidhead , я обращаюсь с вопросом к сообществу. Хотелось бы узнать мнение человека, владеющего, целостной картиной.  Ведь для этого и нужны сообщества.

Comment: @Pyramidhead [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/)

Comment: Пытаясь найти ответ я начал копаться в спецификации HTTP 1.1 и погряз в деталях, а надо было шире смотреть на вещи. Ответ ближе к работе браузера. Я сейчас попробую дать ответ на вопрос сам, ведь не один я им интересовался в рунете. Надеюсь, таким как я ответ поможет. Профессионалам, думаю, он неинтересен, но если его кто-то улучшит, буду благодарен.

Comment: И еще один важный момент. Хочу поблагодарить @NicolasChabanovsky за внимательное отношение к новичкам.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ну да. Для сообщества куда полезнее подобные вопросы.

Comment: @Pyramidhead К сожалению, не понял вашу мысль. Пожалуйста, раскройте ее на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/), если у вас будет минутка.

Answer (score 1):

Ввод URL в адресную строку браузера приводит к формированию GET запроса, потому что именно HTTP-метод GET предназначен для получения/запрашивания содержимого ресурса. При этом пользователь в данном случае взаимодействует с браузером через адресную строку.
В случае же POST запроса, пользователь нажимает кнопку submit в теле самого HTML документа отображенного в браузере. Хотя эта кнопка по умолчанию тоже приводит к формированию GET запроса, но это опять таки будет GET запрос (c отправкой данных веб формы) сформированный после нажатия кнопки submit, а не ввода в адресную строку.